# Overlay multiple images on one base image using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have command to overlay 2 images , and its working fine,

```
"-y -i \(image1) -i \(image2) -filter_complex [0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2 \(out)"
```

I wish to add multiple images 
 for example: we have four images [image1,image2, image3, image4].

Now image1 will be base one, I want to other 3 images on image1 as overlay.

The images place can be vary randomly. 
I have been trying to search this on google, everything redirects to multiple images on video or combine video.

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use multiple [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters. A basic example:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay[bg0];[bg0][2]overlay[bg1];[bg1][3]overlay[v]"
-map "[v]" output
```